# Vertically justify content on collapsed bootstrap row

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css, flexbox, bootstrap-4

I've got two columns in a row and both columns contain a row as well. The left column's row stacks it's columns on top of each other should the page width reach the 'xs' break-point.

The right column's height is bigger than the left column's height. This leads to a lot of empty space on the left column's bottom.

I would like to have the left column spread out the stacked columns over the available space created by the right column.

Bootstrap4's class `justify-content-between` and the css property `justify-content: space-between;` seem the be a good bet, but I have no idea how to use them in this context.

Help would be much appreciated, thanks!

Fiddle [`here`](https://jsfiddle.net/hnhyoh11/) and snippet below:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">

    <!-- left column -->
    <div class="col-6">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12 col-md-4">column 1</div>
        <div class="col-12 col-md-4">column 2</div>
        <div class="col-12 col-md-4">column 3</div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- right column -->
    <div class="col-6">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12">
          <p>
            imagine this col was really tall, and I wish the columns one, two, and three from the left col would justify between themselves to match the overall height of this column
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: just to be clear, you want 3 columns in the left and a single 1 in the right?

Comment: @EdgarHenriquez I'd like to have the 3 columns from the left column occupy the whole vertical space created by the right column.

Answer (score 1):

You can just add `h-100` class to the `row` element in the first column - see demo below:

```css
.container > .row > .col-6 > .row > div {
  border: 1px solid #ddd; /* border for illustration */
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">

    <!-- left column -->
    <div class="col-6">
      <div class="row h-100"> <!-- <= added h-100 class here -->
        <div class="col-12 col-md-4">column 1</div>
        <div class="col-12 col-md-4">column 2</div>
        <div class="col-12 col-md-4">column 3</div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- right column -->
    <div class="col-6">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12">
          <p>
            imagine this col was really tall, and I wish the columns one, two, and three from the left col would justify between themselves to match the overall height of this column
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```